# Gruntfile.js, Autoprefixer and bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Tags: magento2, setup, deployment

The vanilla checkout of Magento2 contains a **Grunt boilerplate** including the `autoprefixer` task. It works all sweet and dandy (according to our frontend devs).

However now as I need to make the whole application working in deployment, we're not using Grunt but the the given Magento bin command with the `setup:static-content:deploy` action (`php -f bin/magento -- setup:static-content:deploy`).

But there somehow the autoprefixer looks lost. Now I'm puzzled which configuration point I was missing or is it so that the Grunt example is not-so-related to actual bare work that has to be done shipping the Magento2 application?

Comment: X-Ref: [CSS and Tooling in Magneto 2 (Quick Note)](https://alankent.me/2016/01/22/css-and-tooling-in-magento-2-quick-note/) (Jan 2016, by Alan Kent)

Comment: X-Ref: Gruntfile.js boilerplate: [magento2/Gruntfile.js.sample](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/Gruntfile.js.sample)

Comment: Sadly if you use the "official" frontend workflow you cannot rely on common tools like autoprefixer because there isn't a php port of this tool. For reference https://alankent.me/2016/10/01/conventions-for-sass-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

Grunt is essential for frontend development and speeds up the dev process and yes you won't be using it in production. Magento commands (initialised from `bin/magento`) should work alongside your Grunt setup, they're completely independent of each other.

In development you can basically run both `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` and grunt exec: one after another and both should work. If your Magento commands are not executing you need to look into whether it was installed and setup correctly, execute the blow command and see if it helps

```
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

If still experiencing issues, you can look into file ownership etc best source is DevDocs http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html

Comment: Can you confirm that `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` completely lacks the autofixer that grunt has preconfigured?

Comment: From what I understand, autoprefixer is only used by Grunt and has no bearing on Magento commands. If I disable/uninstall autoprefixer (which is a node module)  my Grunt complaints but bin/magento commands work as normal. 99.9% sure it's not required by Magento core commands.

Answer (score 0):

We experienced some minor differences between the grunt workflow and just using static content deploy. To ensure deployment creates the same result as development and we changed the prod function in the gruntfile:

```
    /**
     * Production preparation task.
     */
    prod: function (component) {
        var tasks = [
            'less',
            'autoprefixer',
            'cssmin',
            'usebanner'
        ].map(function(task){
            return task + ':' + component;
        });

        if (typeof component === 'undefined') {
            _.each(themes, function(theme, name) {
                tasks = [
                    'less',
                    'autoprefixer',
                    'cssmin',
                    'usebanner'
                ].map(function(task){
                    return task + ':' + name;
                });
                grunt.task.run(tasks);
            });
        } else {
            grunt.task.run(tasks);
        }
    }
```

This also includes the autoprexer and cssmin. You will need to create .js files for these however and use combo.js to get all your css files. We added a 'cssFiles' function in there. By default it only contains a 'lessFiles' function. It was not all that hard.

```
cssFiles: function (themeName) {
    var cssStringArray = [],
        cssFiles = {},
        i = 0;

    for (i; i < theme[themeName].files.length; i++) {
        cssStringArray[i] = path.pub +
        theme[themeName].area + '/' +
        theme[themeName].name + '/' +
        theme[themeName].locale + '/' +
        theme[themeName].files[i] + '.css';

        cssFiles[cssStringArray[i]] = cssStringArray[i];
    }

    return cssFiles;
}
```